# Xcode 14 No Platform For watch Although I Downloaded WatchOS 9.0 Simulator Now Redownload it Gives Error Duplicated

Tags: xcode, macos, watchos, developer-tools

My Xcode 14.01 was working fine and Run On the iOS And WatchOS Perfectly then one time I Notice it give me error with new build Saying No WatchOS Platform and I'm Sure I Already Download it.
So I go To Settings and try to download it again then An Error Of Duplicated was there , But I Notice That My WatchOS Platform Is Already There With Same Size With word beside it saying On Disk, But Why its Not Working.

Here is what I see In Menu Xcode -> Settings -> Platform

[image]

So Should I Remove the One There And Re Download again In fact It Is Quite Much To Download 3.6 GB Every time Or Should I Re Install The Xcode 14.01 Again

My System Is like that
MacOS : Ventura macOS 14.0
MacBook Air M1 2020

thanx For Help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After two days I figure it out, Xcode Mounting the watchOS and TvOS Images when you Download it first time so my guess is I unmount it manually when I was upgrading to Ventura macOS and solution is very easy and cost no more downloads is to locate it and mount it manually.

Open Terminal And Write:

```
xcrun simctl runtime add
```

This would remount the simulator images again into Xcode

P.S. Do not try to mount the simulator images using Disk Utility or by double click it, as this won't add it to Xcode you need to add it and mount it using the xcrun simctl runtime command

[image]

[image]

[image]

References:

According To Apple Xcode 14 Release Notes:
It Seems If you manually unmount or detach a simulator runtime disk image (such as by using diskutil eject or umount), Simulator and Xcode may not be able to determine whether the runtime is installed or not. Attempts to re-download the runtime results in failure with a duplicate runtime error. (89589210)

Workaround:

Restarting causes Simulator to re-mount the runtime disk image.

If this not work so Use xcrun simctl runtime add in Terminal to Remount The Images Manually

Alternately you can use xcrun simctl runtime to locate the affected runtime disk image, delete it, then use Xcode to re-download it.

Comment: (Xcode 15.0) This led me to my solution. Thank you.  

I unmounted the images in disk utility because I was getting excessive disk writes on sleep. I thought the 7 mounted simulators might be related, didn't verify. I couldn't remount the images via finder. Some would, other would say 'The operation couldn’t be completed. Permission denied'. 

The simplest solution was to run in terminal `xcrun simctl runtime delete 'iOS 17.0'`. And then Xcode would let me re-download the simulator.